# htaccess redirect sub directory to deeper sub directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to figure out how to redirect a sub directory to deeper sub directory. I would like to do something like this:

Redirect /subdir1 to /subdir1/subdir2/subdir3

Eveything I have tried either just does not work or gets into an infinite loop.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RedirectMatch` instead for its regex capabilities:

```
RedirectMatch ^/subdir1/?$ /subdir1/subdir2/subdir3
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, too much to learn about htaccess functionality